Connect-AzAccount Could not load type 'System.Diagnostics.Metrics.Meter' from assembly 'System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource
Everything that I have found with a similar error seems to be for developers working in their C# / Visual Studio environment.  I'm just trying to connect to Azure with Powershell.  This seems to be a problem only with Powershell versions that are newer than 5.1.17763.5576.  I have other VM's where things work fine and are practically identical, but the Powershell version is 5.1.17763.5576 or older.  So, to state it plainly, my credentials are not the problem, and updating PowerShell to the latest is not the solution.
PS C:\Windows\system32> $psversiontable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.17763.6292
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.17763.6292
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1


PS C:\Windows\system32> connect-azaccount
Please select the account you want to login with.

WARNING: Unable to acquire token for tenant 'organizations' with error 'InteractiveBrowserCredential authentication
failed: Could not load type 'System.Diagnostics.Metrics.Meter' from assembly 'System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource,
Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.'
WARNING: Please run 'Connect-AzAccount -DeviceCode' if browser is not supported in this session.
connect-azaccount : InteractiveBrowserCredential authentication failed: Could not load type
'System.Diagnostics.Metrics.Meter' from assembly 'System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=5.0.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
At line:1 char:1
+ connect-azaccount
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Connect-AzAccount], AuthenticationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.ConnectAzureRmAccountCommand

How do I fix this?
Things I've tried that do not work:
Update-Module -Name Az -Force  (does not fix this)
Uninstall/Reinstall Module     (does not fix this)

After playing with this more, I found that the problem is specifically AFTER I load my .psm1 PS module and instantiate it:  ( It only happens after I [MyClass]::new() )

Don't you think updating the PowerShell module to the latest version will resolve your issue? Update-Module -Name Az -Force

No, because it's the newest version that has the problem, not the older versions, as I stated.

The solution was that I needed to:
Import-Module Az.Accounts

before loading my modules, or within my class definition itself.
class MyClass {
    [string]$azureTenantId

    # Constructor
    MyClass () {

    }

    [void] connectAzAccount(){
        #this is required        
        Import-Module Az.Accounts
        Connect-AzAccount -TenantId $this.azureTenantId
    }

    [void] setTenantId([string]$tenantId){
        $this.azureTenantId = $tenantId
    }
}


This error occurs because of a version mismatch between your PowerShell environment and the System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource assembly that Connect-AzAccount relies on. You can just update your PowerShell module
Update-Module -Name Az -Force

Now check again (as you can see this is now updated from 5.1.17763.6292 to 5.1.26100.1882)


and then login using the -DeviceCode parameter to authenticate via device code
Connect-AzAccount -DeviceCode


You can always reinstall for a clean slate
Uninstall-Module -Name Az 
Install-Module -Name Az

or if possible, try running in PS 7, as it has better compatibility with the Az module.
References:

Troubleshooting the Az PowerShell module
Troubleshoot development environment authentication


None of this worked.
